# filtering measures based on two columns in power bi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to use a measure and filter the result based on the columns:

My measure is :

```
TotalProductionCon =
SUM ( _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[SGWCP8] )
    + SUM ( _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[retard] )
```

and I want it to summarize only when column année = column year.

I tried `CALCULATE` and `FILTER`;

```
TotalProductionCon =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[SGWCP8] )
        + SUM ( _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[retard] );
    FILTER (
        ALL ( _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[Année] );
        _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[Année] = _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[year]
    )
)
```

but it generates an error that the columns contain much value and I need to use aggregation.

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried filtering by the column only? i.e. TotalProductionCon =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[SGWCP8] )
        + SUM ( _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[retard] );
        _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[Année] = _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[year]
    
) This will reduce the memory required to process the DAX query.

Comment: It generates this error :The expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your formula is that you limited ALL function to only one column (Annee), and as a result FILTER does not "see" the other column it needs.

To fix that, change your formula as follows:

```
TotalProductionCon =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[SGWCP8] )
        + SUM ( _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[retard] );
    FILTER (
        ALL (
            _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[Année];
            _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[year]
        );
        _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[Année] = _BI_SOVAC_PROD_KIT_LIFE_CYCLE[year]
    )
)
```

I am assuming here that your choice of ALL function is appropriate; otherwise you might need to use a different technique such as SUMMARIZE function.